# Can't get the method to work

Tags: java

I have this method here, which converts an image to a byte array.

```
public byte[] imageToCompressedByteArray(Image image) throws IOException {
//load the image
String f = "C:\\Users\\mamed\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Main\\src\\resources\\accept.png";
image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(new File(f)));


// get image size
int width = image.getWidth(null);
int height = image.getHeight(null);


try {
  int[] imageSource = new int[width * height];
  PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0, width, height, imageSource, 0, width);
  pg.grabPixels();


  ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
  GZIPOutputStream zippedStream = new GZIPOutputStream(byteStream);
  ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(zippedStream);
  objectStream.writeShort(width);
  objectStream.writeShort(height);
  objectStream.writeObject(imageSource);
  objectStream.flush();
  objectStream.close();
  return byteStream.toByteArray();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  throw new IOException("Error storing image in object: " + e);
}
```

}

However, i can't get this to work, i mean, it can't load the image and convert it, and i don't have an idea what the problem can be.

Comment: Use a debugger and try to figure out in which line is the problem ... is the file really opened ? Are the streams are initialized correctly ?

Comment: we need more input: stacktrace? what error are oyu getting? how can you tell it is not working

Comment: I really doubt GZIP compression of an image is more efficient than PNG compression. You'd better leave your images as is.

Comment: Please provide an exact error message.  What exactly happened when this code executed.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Are you sure your path for the image is correct, generally maven structure uses dir main with lowercase and not as Main

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the image path is correct and the loaded image is not corrupted image.

I not modified your code and I can see 1778416 byes its read from the image file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with the program. Maybe your image file is corrupted or image path is not correct.